# Can eye drops cure dry eyes?

Tags: eye

When waking up on every morning it takes several minutes before I can clearly see (I have to blink quite a lot). During the day it's common to feel irritation, like I had soap on my eye. I've tried over dozen eye drop brands suggested by professionals, none having *any* discernible effect, bringing only temporary relief. I currently think I shouldn't spend money at all on eye drops.

Comment: Hi! Interesting. When you mean by "professionals", you mean an "ophtalmologist"? Dry eyes is a very common symptom. However, in some cases they may be associated with an underlying condition. If obviously, none of the eyes drops are helping, I think, it would be worth seeing an eye specialist (=ophtalmologist). Best regards. M. Arrowsmith.

Comment: @M.Arrowsmith No, only my local optician. I doubt I've ever have been in touch with an actual doctor (but I will soon).

Comment: Good idea! Good luck, best regards. M. Arrowsmith

Answer (score 2):

Here are some other [home remedies that can help ease your dry eye symptoms](http://www.belmarrahealth.com/dry-eyes-and-seasonal-allergies-linked-treat-dry-eyes-naturally-with-home-remedies/):

**Apply warm compress:** Because dry eyes can occur due to lack of tears, applying a warm compress may unclog your tear glands, allowing the production of tears and relieving dry eye symptoms.

**Blink:** Our bodies naturally lubricate our eyes through blinking. Make sure you are blinking often, especially when concentrating on a computer screen or sitting in front of a TV. Blinking can also help remove dust and debris from your eyes and prevent irritation.

**Wear protective eye gear:** Sunglasses are an easy solution to your dry eye problem because they can block the sunlight and the wind – both dry eye causes.

**Stay hydrated:** Because our bodies require water for all major functions, it’s no surprise that drinking enough water is a dry eye treatment. In particular, on hotter days, make sure you’re getting adequate hydration, and if you find water boring, add in fruits and vegetables.

**Apply cucumbers:** Because of their water content, placing cucumbers on the eyes can keep them moist and lubricated – an effective dry eyes home remedy indeed.

**Reduce coffee consumption:** Coffee can worsen your dry eye condition, so cutting back on your intake may help relieve dry eye symptoms.

Comment: Does using glasses help? I wear glasses all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Most over the counter eye drops only provide temporary relief for dry eyes by actually adding liquid to the eye. Once the liquid added evaporates, gets absorbed, or is removed in one way or another your eyes will feel dry again unless your eyes are able to adequately lubricate themselves. So most eye drops aren't treating any underlying cause, just the temporary symptoms of dry eye. If this is a frequent problem I'd look to see if any other medications you're taking could be causing the dry eyes as a side effect. If you're not taking any other medications that could be causing this, seeing an optometrist or ophthalmologist sounds like a good idea.

Edit: I should also mention, there is a medication approved for chronic dry eye called Restasis. It is prescription only however.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try warm compresses for dry eyes; they help the glands in your eyelids secrete good oils for lubrication

Comment: I've done that, I feel that method is more effective than none of the eye drops I have used.