# How to cure a dry eye

Tags: eye, treatment

My friend's sister has a dry eye, she has tried using eye drop but to no avail, pls what else can she do to cure the dry eye and what caused the dry eye

Comment: I recommend a warm compress; you can buy a good one at drug stores. Someone asked similar question here - http://health.stackexchange.com/questions/8890/can-eye-drops-cure-dry-eyes/8940#8940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mild to moderate cases of dry eye syndrome can usually be treated using lubricant eye treatments that consist of a range of drops, gels and ointments. These lubricants are often called artificial tears because they replace the missing water in the tear film. For more information on other treatments for different other causes, visit the website below.                                                     http://www.nhs.uk/Conditions/Dry-eye-syndrome/Pages/Treatment.aspx